# jmeter Regular Expression Extractor to extract string from multi string

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have multiple string of grp and name in the response message. I want to extract the grp based on unique name ,"grp":(.+?),"name":"UNIQUE_STRING"

> Regular Expression Extractor 
>   Reference Name: group_name Regular
>
> Expression: "grp":(.+?),"name":"UNIQUE_STRING" Template : $1$ Match
>   no: 1

I want to extract the preceding value based on the unique name but not able to find..
Please help

Comment: Can you give example of response message?

Comment: "grp":11111,"name":"test_constant1","target":{"abc","id":1,"id":1,"adminUser":{"id":2},"owner":{"text":"test","name":"TEST"},"targetSystemSource":null}}}],"grp":22222,"name":"test_constant2"

Here based on second name test_constant2 i want to find correspond grp which is 22222. is it posible from regx post processor?

Answer (score 0):

You can find string until the first comma:

```
Regular Expression: grp":([^,]+),"name":"UNIQUE_STRING
```

If you want to remove " in grp value (find 123 for grp":"123") use:

```
Regular Expression: grp":"([^,]+)","name":"UNIQUE_STRING
```

Comment: There is two different grp here. i want to find the second grp value>>

EG: "grp":11111,"name":"test_constant1","target":{"abc","id":1,"id":1,"adminUser":{"id":2},"owner":{"text":"test","name":"TEST"},"targetSystemSource":null}}}],"grp":22222,"name":"test_constant2",

Comment: Replace UNIQUE_STRING with constant2

Answer (score 0):

Your response is utterly like to be a [JSON](http://www.json.org/), if this is the case I believe it will be **much** easier to use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) (available since JMeter 3.0)

If your response data looks something like:

```
[
  {
    "grp": "foo",
    "name": "UNIQUE_STRING"
  },
  {
    "grp": "bar",
    "name": "ANOTHER_STRING"
  }
]
```

You should be able to extract this `foo` value using a simple [Json Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) query like: `$..[?(@.name == 'UNIQUE_STRING')].grp`

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSONPath Conditional Select]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)